# Gatling: Set the report directory name?

Tags: testing, load, gatling

I'd like to customize the Gatling report directory created as a result of a test execution.

By default, report directories are written (using `gatling-maven-plugin`) under :

`target/gatling/<simulation-class-name>-<timestamp>`

Is it possible to configure the report directory name like:

`target/gatling/<my-dynamically-determined-name>-<timestamp>`

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can override in the command you use to kick off the simulation execution.

eg: passing -Dgatling.core.outputDirectoryBaseName=abc results in an output folder with the name `abc-<timestamp>`

Comment: And in case if i want to remove timestamp from target/gatling/<simulation-class-name>-<timestamp>
any idea how can I do that?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Pass your argument as -rf "YOUR LOCATION"

```
java -cp target/gatling-java-example.jar io.gatling.app.Gatling -s "com.jay.platform.perf.BasicSimulation" -rf "results"
```